# Custom SOLR-sorting that is aware of its neighbours

Tags: solr

For a SOLR search, I want to treat some results differently (where the field "is_promoted" is set to "1") to give them a better ranking. After the "normal" query is performed, the order of the results should be rearranged so that approximately 30 % of the results in a given range (say, the first 100 results) should be "promoted results". The ordering of the results should otherwise be preserved.

I thought it would be a good idea to solve this by making a custom SOLR plugin. So I tried writing a SearchComponent, but it seems like you can't change the ordering of search results after it has passed through the QueryComponent (since they are cached)?

One could have written some kind of custom sort function (or a function query?) but the challenge is that the algorithm needs to know about the score/ordering of the other surrounding results. A simple increase in the score won't do the trick.

Any suggestions on how this should be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just answered this question on the Solr users list. The RankQuery feature in Solr 4.9 is designed to solve this type of problem. You can read about RankQueries here: http://heliosearch.org/solrs-new-rankquery-feature/

Comment: happy to give the very first rep to Joel Bernstein :-p